# Qual é o critério para que uma pergunta apareça na zona "Debates mais ativos"?

Tags: suporte, boletim-da-comunidade

Existe algum critério definido para que uma pergunta, aqui do meta, seja apresentada na zona "Debates mais ativos" na parte lateral da página?

Quem gere essa zona? São os moderadores ou o critério é aplicado automaticamente(robot)?

Comment: Pelo que conheço da SE até agora, acredito se tratar de um algoritmo complexo envolvendo zilhões de variáveis. Te garanto que os moderadores não tem nada a ver com isso, talvez os funcionários, mas não sei lhe dizer. Um dos requisitos para que a pergunta apareça ali é que ela tenha a meta tag [meta-tag:debate], pontuação e idade provavelmente são bem importantes.

Comment: @Math Pergunto porque tenho visto perguntas recentes, com menos pontuação, menos respostas e comentários que outras que não aparecem. Podia dar vários exemplos mas o mais recente é esta: [*Logotipo do SOpt de casamento igualitário*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4046/2541).

Comment: Pra mim aparece aleatoriamente, mas notei que as vezes uma pergunta fica em destaque e mesmo que eu atualize ela sempre fica lá, deve ser algo como `atividade recente`+`aletorio`+`cache do servidor`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Como é possível aos moderadores colocarem as perguntas na zona *"Em destaque no Meta"* pensei que eles pudessem fazer o mesmo em relação à zona *"Debates mais ativos"* mas o Math diz que não. Enfim, gostaria de perceber o mecanismo.

Comment: Tem dois destaques o *Em destaque no Meta* e o *Debates mais ativos*, provavelmente eles controlam apenas o "Em destaque no Meta" ... Se eu fosse chutar como funciona, diria que o "Debates mais ativos" devem ter a tag `debate` e devem fazer referencia somente ao último dia ou hora.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não, no momento que estou a escrever este comentário os que aparecem têm dois ou mais dias.

Comment: @ramaral não é "atividade" como "comentar" ou "responder", eu acho que é algo baseado em porcentagem de "leituras"

Comment: Eu não sei a regra exata, mas a parte de "debates mais ativos" é controlada automaticamente. Os moderadores podem, sim, decidir 3 posts para usar a tag `destaque`, que vão aparecer no quadro, mas o resto é automático

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essas são as regras

- Se uma eleição estiver acontecendo, vai haver um link para ela no quadro.
- **Eventos** podem ser criados, com título, duração e um link com mais informações. São listados os eventos ocorrendo no momento e os que estão para acontecer, com os mais próximos de começar ou terminar aparecendo primeiro.
- Caso existam menos de 4 eventos, vão aparecer posts do blog do [blog do Stack Exchange](http://blog.stackexchange.com/). Só aparecem posts dos últimos 3 dias, e no máximo 2 posts diferentes.
- Se, depois disso, ainda existirem menos de 4 itens no quadro, aparecem os posts em **[destaque](/questions/tagged/destaque) no meta**. Desde que tenham pontuação positiva.
- Se ainda houver menos de 4 itens, o espaço é preenchido com os **[debates](/questions/tagged/debates) "interessantes"**¹ do Meta. Estas perguntas não podem ter [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto), devem ter pelo menos 3 pontos e terem menos de 2 semanas. A escolha é semi-aleatória. *Pelo menos 1* dessas perguntas é inserida, mesmo que torna a lista maior que 4 itens.

As URLs são verificadas para que não haja posts repetidos (evitando que, por exemplo, um debate interessante, em destaque, que esteja relacionado a um evento não apareça 3 vezes na lista).

**Além disso**, podem aparecer até 2 posts recentes (até 2 semanas) marcados com [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) no **Meta Stack Exchange**. Esses posts aparecem no quadro de todos os sites da rede. Lembre-se que eles não contam para o limite de 4 links, então a lista pode acabar sendo mais longa que o normal em algumas ocasiões.

<sup>Traduzido de [How are the contents of the Community Bulletin determined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/175506)</sup>

---

¹ A [fórmula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/175506) para perguntas consideradas "interessantes" é:

```
(log(visitasP)*4) + ((respostasP * pontuaçãoP)/5) + sum(pontuaçãoA)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    ((idadeHorasP+1) - ((idadeHorasP - atualizaçãoP)/2)) ^ 1.5
```

Comment: Tinha que ter um logaritmo e um expoente de uma constante fracionária completamente aleatória na fórmula para deixá-la bem doida :)

Comment: @Math Não é a primeira, nem a última coisa, que o Jeff Atwood faz mais complicado do que devia ser ;)